# Custom border skin to textarea mobile flex

Tags: apache-flex, border, skin

I like to give custom border skin to TextArea on all four side with some Specific **color, alpha and weight** value. like `color:#f2f2f2;` and `alpha:2`.

I search lot but didn't get any proper solution. Textarea  will take default border if, i give visible true, but it looks bad or didn't match to my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create custom skin for your text area, as the basis take a spark.skins.spark.TextAreaSkin. And set the own border

`<s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:stroke>
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1"/>
        </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>`